HTTPS\SSL authentication for users
As I suddenly figured out, there is plain HTTP used on log-in form to http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com
No SSL\HTTPS implemented, and password in login form transferred in clear text.
As You may see, this is not secure at all.
Workaround I found for myself - log in at https://stackexchange.com/ and then - use Login button on reverseengineering.stackexchange.com to extend login session to subdomain as well. It's not 100% secure also, but at least not credential but session passed in clear text here.
So - question is, is there any option to enable secure login directly to project website, without workarounds? 
UPDATE: well, always re-check results before You ask questions. 
Actual OpenID form URL is https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form
So - problem is partially solved.
Anyway - site with information related to InfoSec IMHO should at least have SSL available for all traffic, even if it not default.

2 years later, has there been any change? I find it curiously targeted, if intentional and not just negligence, etc..

We implemented HTTPS everywhere on Stack Exchange a very long time ago - just updating this now to reflect that.

HTTPS connections to the questions and answers site have been requested for a long time but are currently not supported.
If you're using Stack Exchange as your OpenID provider, you can connect to https://stackexchange.com/ and log in there. Even if you connect to http://stackexchange.com/, assuming you haven't been redirected to another site by an active man-in-the-middle, your credentials are not sent in cleartext — the login form does use HTTPS. That still leaves your session cookie exposed to potential hijacking.
Some prior requests and discussions on the topic:

Why doesn't the Stack Overflow team fix the Firesheep style cookie theft?
StackExchange OpenID provider should clearly use HTTPS
Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites
https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/why-doesnt-security-stackexchange-com-use-https
https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/are-there-plans-to-support-https


Well, it is right. Actual FORM URL redirected to https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form

There's other practical reasons to use SSL, and it's something we're working on. For instance, caching proxies kill web sockets, so going over 443 is the best fix - and if you're going to 443, you might as well have SSL. I just don't know when it's going to finally happen.
